# How to get full permission on client

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, permissions, file-sharing

When sharing a folder across the network with Windows 7 on the server, and Windows XP on the client, how can we give full permissions to the client?

Comment: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Networking-home-computers-running-different-versions-of-Windows

Comment: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Share-files-with-someone

Answer (score 2):

Two steps to be sure of this:

- Verify the Share permissions allow Full Control

  1. Modify the Share properties
  2. On the Permissions tab, make sure that "Everyone" has Full Control (note: this does not grant the Full Control right, it merely allows Full Control NTFS permissions to be used)
- Verify the NTFS permissions are set to permit Full Control to your client.

  1. Check the permissions of the Share's directory
  2. Make sure your Client has the correct rights (using a group for this is best-practice).